# Adding extra columns along with a UNION

Tags: sql-server-2008, union, temp-tables

The following shows two attempts at trying to insert data into a temp table using both a union query along with two extra columns (fldBF and sCount)...

CASE 1:

```
SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount 
INTO #tmpTable 
FROM V_qryCSPGA 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK 
      FROM FN_qryAllDTPK()) 
UNION ALL   
SELECT * 
FROM FN_qryCSGBA() 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK())
ORDER BY fldPK, fldCIA, fldNDat;
```

CASE 2:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpTable        
FROM V_qryCSPGA 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK()) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount
FROM FN_qryCSGBA() 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK())
ORDER BY fldPK, fldCIA, fldNDat;
```

In either case I receive the following error... 'All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.' Is there anyway for me to circumvent this without having to do a whole other insert of some sort?

Comment: Please format your queries to make them readable. Why don't you first check if the number of columns are equal as per error message?

Comment: Done, and I receive the same error message in either case, I don't receive the error message if I remove ', 1 AS fldBF, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY 
       fldPK) AS sCount ' from each of the queries.

Comment: In each case, run both select queries separately and check if they are giving same number of columns in the result sets. Also check if corresponding data types are same (or at least implicitly convertible to the data type of the first query). You have to make sure both conditions are satisfied.

Comment: There is no result set, the extra columns that I am trying to add end up halting execution otherwise the queries are exactly the same. I need to figure out a way to include the two columns so that I can return a result set with everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure both select queries are returning equal number of columns. As per comments, if you need to include extra columns, you can add static values to the other select query. So,

Adding (-1) as static values your CASE 1 would be like;

```
SELECT *, 1 AS fldBF, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fldPK, fldCIA ORDER BY fldPK) AS sCount 
INTO #tmpTable 
FROM V_qryCSPGA 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK()) 

UNION ALL   

SELECT *, -1 AS fldBF, -1 AS sCount --NOTE: Two static fields 
FROM FN_qryCSGBA() 
WHERE fldPK IN(SELECT DISTINCT thePK FROM FN_qryAllDTPK())
ORDER BY fldPK, fldCIA, fldNDat;
```

You could do the same thing to the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not equivalent.  As the error message says, **both** select statements must contain the same columns.  In your first example, only your first select statement has `fldBF` and `sCount`.  In your second example, only your second query has `fldBF` and `sCount`.  Because you are using the `SELECT *` syntax, you also can experience this issue if one table has more/less columns than the other.

You didn't post what the two input tables look like, so I'm going to assume they are slightly different tables.  My suggestion would be to use a query like the following.

You may be able to remove the `IN` statements and use a join, but again I don't know what your tables look like.

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY field1) AS custField1, 
    1 AS myInt, 
    * 
INTO #tmp_tbl 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        field1, 
        field2, 
        field3, 
        'X' AS field4 
    FROM V_qryCSPGA 
    WHERE my_pk IN (SELECT DISTINCT some_pk FROM My_Fn())
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        'A' AS field1, 
        field5 AS field2, 
        field3, 
        field4 
    FROM FN_qryCSGBA()
) X;
```